# Setting up SVN repository on Remote machine with XCode 4.0

Tags: xcode, git-svn

I have followed the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW12) to setup the SVN repository for existing project. I followed following steps:

```
mkdir branches
mkdir tags
mkdir trunk
cp -R /myProject /SVN_Master/trunk
svnadmin create myProject_svn
svn import trunk/myProject file:///SVN_Master/myProejct_svn -m "Initial import"
```

It has set up SVN repository now. How can I checkout this? It isn't working when I try to checkout from XCode organizer, give path file:///SVN_Master/myProejct_svn. Am I missing something?

How could I setup the same thing for remote host(my server)? Can I just copy created local repository there and use that path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this sorted. It was annoying though as Apple's documentation on this doesn't made any sense. The simple steps you should follow is,

1. Setup the SVN repository on remote Windows server. I used [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/). I was able to setup in couple of minutes.
2. From MAC, checkout the code from terminal using "svn co http://serverurl/svn/projectname localdir" command.
3. Open the project.xcodeproj file and it will try to create repository for you automatically. Make sure that you enter correct user/pass when asked for.