# XCode 4.1 won't connect to my VisualSVN Windows server

Tags: xcode, visualsvn

I installed the free version of VisualSVN on my networked Windows 7 server.

The link looks like this:  https://sedwo@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/svn/iOS

On my MBP,
I can login and view the repository through firefox.
I bought Cornerstone 2 and can view the repository using https.  (not svn://)

I read "[Setting up SVN repository on Remote machine with XCode 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963886/setting-up-svn-repository-on-remote-machine-with-xcode-4-0)" and notice that XCode 4.1 picks up the svn details from the project file.

Yet it still does not make the connection.

**And I just don't know why?**

In addition, XCode doesn't even save the password to the repository when I restart it.

So I'm out of ideas of where else to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As weird as it is, I finally got this working.

My MBP is connected over Wifi, so I turned OFF the wifi, then turned it back ON, while XCode is running, and suddenly it caused XCode to pop-up a certificate verification dialog for the IP where my SVN repo exists.

I clicked on 'Continue' and suddenly the connection was made.

Weird.  :/

Anyway, perhaps this might help others too.

Enjoy.